# Does $f(n)$ approach infinity as $n$ approaches infinity if $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and is bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and is bijective. Is it true that $$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(n) = \infty ?
$$

---

My attempt: Say that $f$ has a limit $L$ at $n=x$. There are only a finite number of values below this limit so one of $f(x+1)$, $f(x+2)$, ... $f(x+L)$, $f(x+L+1)$ is greater than the limit. Q.E.D.

---

Is this correct?

Comment: What is the question? There is something missing...

Comment: I assume you meant to say $\lim_{n\to \infty} f(n)=\infty$?

Comment: Your approach is not good.  True, you can use it to show that the limit can't be any finite number but that does not prove that the limit is infinite.  After all, the limit might fail to exist.  You need to actually show that the limit exists and equals $\infty$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

This is true even under the weaker assumption that $f$ takes each value finitely many times.

Take $n\ge 1$ natural. The set $f^{-1}(\{1,2,\ldots, n\})$ is finite. Let $M_n$ an upper bound for it. Then $f(m) >n$ for all $m> M_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have put the `proof-verification` tag to your post, here it is:

> Say that $f$ has a limit $L$ at $n=x$.
>
> `(This is an invalid assumption: what you want to show is` $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty$`. "Limit at` $n=x$ `" does not make sense. Secondly, even if you have proved that"` $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$`cannot be true for any real number L", you would not have finished the proof because` $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=L$ `for some` $L$ `is not the contrapositive of` $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=\infty$`.)`
>
> There are only a finite number of values below this limit so one of $$f(x+1), f(x+2), ... f(x+L), f(x+L+1)$$ is greater than the limit. Q.E.D. `(Mission not complete.)`

---

> Is this correct?`(Not yet.)`